# Observable function not getting called

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I need to execute `getData()` and then proceed with another call `getOtherData` But I have an issue of my `getData()` not getting executed. Also I need to return data from `this.service.getOtherData()` so I can't use `.subscribe()` Here is how I composed my operators.

My first call I need to make:

```
public getData(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>(apiUrl)
}
```

Does not work:

```
myFunction() {
    this.service.getData().pipe(
        tap(data => {
            doStuff(data); // not getting here
        }),
        switchMap(() => {
            return this.service.getOtherData().pipe(
                tap((data) => {
                    sc.dispatch(new DoSomethingElse(data));
                }),
                catchError(err => of(tap(() => {})))
            );
        })
    );
}
```

Any thoughts how to fix?

Comment: using .subscribe instead of .pipe

Comment: @RobertChan @NitinSingh i need to return the data from `this.service.getOtherData()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call .subscribe inorder to get them called,

```
this.dataService.getData()
      .pipe(
        tap(console.log),
        tap(data => doStuff(data)))
      ).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public getData(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>(apiUrl).subscribe();
}
```